# Is there a way to have a constructor return an object that == null in Java?

Tags: java

I have a feeling the answer is "no" but thought I'd ask just in case...

pseudo code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

if(foo != null){
    foo.useMe();
}else{
   System.out.println("foo failed to initialize");
}
```

What would I have to do in Foo to make this a reality?

Comment: It is not possible to happen.

Comment: This Q is not clear. A constructor doesn't return anything.

Comment: You could use a factory method instead, i.e. `Foo foo = createNewFoo(...);`

Comment: Why do you want to do that. There is no good reason to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you would just have it throw an exception for this situation. You can easily write your own exception or just use something like `throw new Exception("foo failed to initialize");` and capture that.

Writing your own Exception: http://www.javaplex.com/blog/java-creating-custom-exceptions/

Comment: I guess that's better than nothing :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel actually don't understimate the power and expresivness of exceptions

Comment: yeah, I like this approach best for this question, but the factory one is quite elegant as well.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no way to have a new object be `null`. This, of course, assumes that there was not an error in the constructor, but if there is, then you will not be able to use the variable anyway.

For more information on the Class Instance Creation Expression, I recommend the [language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9).

Comment: that's what I thought... but figured I'd double check... would have been useful, though! :)

Comment: How useful? Just throw an exception if you want to signal an initialization failure in `Foo`.

Comment: @BalusC, I agree... syntactically I find it more elegant to test for null, since that's how most invalid objects are located, but you're right, it's not any sort of big deal.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of languages use a null/nil check for invalidity. Not many languages really push exceptions as flow control as hard as Java does.

Comment: @PatrickPerini You mean except C++, C#, Python,.. - heck which language allows you to return null (and how would the syntax look for that) from a constructor? Don't know even one.

Comment: @Voo, I imagine the constructor would simply return null. Stranger things have happened :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Well one could, but it seems like a really bad idea without any redeeming feature (apart from "I don't like exceptions", in which case Java is certainly the wrong language to begin with). Anyways since we were talking about constructors and Patrick said lots of languages allowed null checks for invalidity I thought I'd just mention that no language I'm aware of actually does this (now that happens often enough in functions, but then lots of java functions also return null in case of error).

Comment: @Voo, being critical of some minor design decision of a language is a far cry from it being "the wrong language".  I'm not thrilled with Strings being immutable either, but that doesn't mean I'm going to switch to PHP.  I realize that technically constructors don't return anything, but syntactically it APPEARS like they do (foo = New Foo() )... so, it seems entirely reasonable to desire a return null feature in a constructor.  Reasonable people can disagree, no?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Sure, but reasonable (for a varying amount of reasonable ;-)) people can also love to discuss language features - and that rather emotionally ;) Returning null from the constructor (instead of usually this I assume?) has several "problems": We could suddenly return existing objects, maybe even of a different runtime type (correct static type) and it also would surprise everyone knowing c++, old java, python, c#, etc. And contrary to immutability which has some great advantages which I'm sure we can all agree on, I just don't see them here.

Answer (score 4):

No, constructors have no return value, but whenever you use "new" you get a create a reference to an object. I think what you want is this:

```
class Factory
{
    static MyClass getMyClass()
    {
    if(true or false expression)
        return new MyClass();
    else if(true or false expression)
        return null;
    }

}
```

and then you can create your class like this

```
MyClass bla = Factory.getMyClass();

if(null)
    do something
```

Answer (score 3):

I knew this is impossible; but just out of curiosity, I tried out a piece of code.

```
public class Test {

  public Test () {
    this = null;
  }

}
```

And of course it failed to compile since "this" is final.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. By convention, if an object fails to initialize, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible - you can however throw a checked exception in the constructor which would need to be caught at the other end if you really want this type of behaviour.

In terms of dealing with errors in constructors a Java specialist newsletter looked at this topic a while back. Might be worth a read: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue120.html

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible for a constructor to return null.  If there's a problem creating the object, then the constructor should throw an exception.

Take the `FileInputStream` class for example.  This class is used to read data from a file.  If a non-existent file is passed into the constructor, it throws a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
try{
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
  System.out.println("File 'file.txt' doesn't exist.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a constructor?  If this is truly what you need, why not use a function that can return a new instance of Foo or null?

Answer (score 0):

11 years later and we still have the issue. To summarize the valid responses and add an idea as well:

Idea 1: Create a wrapper class to work like a factory. This wrapper class will create new instances of the inner class if the data is valid. (by user975484)
//Idea 1 is great if you are working solo, but if you are creating an object for a school or company project then you may not be allowed to use a factory.

Idea 2: Throw an exception if data is invalid in the constructor. (by CamelSlack)
//Idea 2 is great as well if the user catches and handles the error. However, you may not be allowed to use this method for school or company rules. I believe that this may be the best solution if you can use it.

Idea 3: return null or default data from functions in the object after verifying data. In essence, run your data verification before running functions.
//Idea 3 might be the only option for students and employees who are forced to follow an overly strict set of requirements. Really isn't useful unless idea 1 and 2 cannot be used.